# R - How to contrast code factors and retain meaningful labels in output summary

Tags: r, r-factor

Ok everyone, once and for all, how do you (emphasis on you, because I'm sure there is more than one way to achieve this) contrast code (treatment, sum, helmert, etc.) and retain a meaningful factor label (so you can make meaningful interpretations of effects) in the glm function?

I understand I can use level() to understand which factor level is the reference, but that get's tedious when I begin to involve factors with 5 or 10 levels and their interactions.

Here is a quick two factor example of what I mean

```
outcome <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1, 0, 0, 1)
firstvar <- c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B")
secondvar <- c("D", "D", "E", "F", "F", "E", "D", "E", "F", "F", "D", "E")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(outcome, firstvar, secondvar))

df$firstvar <- as.factor(df$firstvar)
df$secondvar <- as.factor(df$secondvar)

#not coded manually (and default appears to be dummy or treatment coding)
#gives meaningful factor labels in summary function
summary(glm(outcome ~ firstvar*secondvar, data=df, family="binomial"))

#effects coded
#does not give meaningful factor labels
contrasts(df$firstvar)=contr.sum(3)
contrasts(df$secondvar)=contr.sum(3)
summary(glm(outcome ~ firstvar*secondvar, data=df, family="binomial"))

#dummy coded
contrasts(df$firstvar)=contr.treatment(3); 
contrasts(df$secondvar)=contr.treatment(3); 
summary(glm(outcome ~ firstvar*secondvar, data=df, family="binomial"))
```

Any and all suggestions will be appreciated. This problem has bugged me for a while, and I'm sure there is a simple(ish) solution.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the simple answer (for `contr.treatment` at least), is that you should pass the factor levels to the function, rather than just the total count. In most cases this will set the level names correctly. For example

```
contr.treatment(levels(df$firstvar))

#   B C
# A 0 0
# B 1 0
# C 0 1
```

and then R uses the column names as labels/suffixes on the coefficients in the regression summary. However, even when passing labels, `contr.sum` doesn't like to set column names. Here we can create our own wrapper though.

```
named.contr.sum<-function(x, ...) {
    if (is.factor(x)) {
        x <- levels(x)
    } else if (is.numeric(x) & length(x)==1L) {
        stop("cannot create names with integer value. Pass factor levels")
    }
    x<-contr.sum(x, ...)
    colnames(x) <- apply(x,2,function(x) 
         paste(names(x[x>0]), names(x[x<0]), sep="-")
    )
    x
}
```

Here we are basically calling calling `contr.sum` and just adding column names to the result (plus some error checking). You can run this with

```
named.contr.sum(levels(df$firstvar))

#   A-C B-C
# A   1   0
# B   0   1
# C  -1  -1
```

I decided to use "A-C" and "B-C" as labels, but you could change that in the code if you like. Then running

```
contrasts(df$firstvar)=named.contr.sum(levels(df$firstvar))
contrasts(df$secondvar)=named.contr.sum(levels(df$secondvar))

summary(glm(outcome ~ firstvar*secondvar, data=df, family="binomial"))
```

will give you

Call:

```
glm(formula = outcome ~ firstvar * secondvar, family = "binomial", 
    data = df)

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)              -6.855e+00  5.023e+03  -0.001    0.999
firstvarA-C              -6.855e+00  6.965e+03  -0.001    0.999
firstvarB-C               6.855e+00  6.965e+03   0.001    0.999
secondvarD-F             -6.855e+00  6.965e+03  -0.001    0.999
secondvarE-F             -6.855e+00  6.965e+03  -0.001    0.999
firstvarA-C:secondvarD-F  2.057e+01  8.473e+03   0.002    0.998
firstvarB-C:secondvarD-F -1.371e+01  1.033e+04  -0.001    0.999
firstvarA-C:secondvarE-F  7.072e-10  1.033e+04   0.000    1.000
firstvarB-C:secondvarE-F  6.855e+00  8.473e+03   0.001    0.999
```

Comment: Thanks man! When you say that you "decided to use 'A-C' and 'B-C' as labels, where did you call that in the code? I am used to using relevel and re-running my contrasts to classify the reference level.

Comment: I should have been more clear. It's in the `paste(names(x[x>0]), names(x[x<0]), sep="-")` line. I use the rowname of the value with "1" minus the rowname with value "-1". The paste puts the "-" between those values.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old topic, but I need to clarify for anyone who may read later.

> even when passing labels, contr.sum doesn't like to set column names.

This phenomena happens for good reasons that **Sum coding** compares n-1 levels with the **grand mean**, e.g. B-mean, C-mean, so  labeling `contr.sum` in other ways is a mistake.

See UCLA manual for the reference of all kinds of coding [R LIBRARY CONTRAST CODING SYSTEMS FOR CATEGORICAL VARIABLES](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#User)